# Project from github setup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need help on a Group Project my team and i are working on:
We've seen a youtube video that presents us with a great project, and we're trying to launch it on our pc in order to understand it more and get a better idea.

The project is made with: MongoDB, Express, React, Nodejs, Featuring JWT, Mongoose, Multer, Bcrypt, Sass.

Here's the project: https://github.com/JustFS/mern-project.git

here's what we've got so far after trying to set it up ourselves:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIklR.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIklR.png)

Comment: Did you install the dependencies first? `npm i`?

Comment: I just did  but nothing opened up

Comment: Then run `npm i` before running `npm start`

Comment: yes i did use npm i and next we've tried launching it then but it just did nothing afterwards and showed me no errors in Terminal

Comment: If express isn’t a dependency it needs to be added `npm i express`

Comment: Ok i'll try this real quick

Comment: just installed express and then lauched it again with npm start but it still didnt open on google

Comment: We cannot help with what we cannot see. Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

install dependencies first, as image showing module missing, install modules by running

npm install

Comment: Ok now that i did all went good i think but still nothing opens up

Comment: you followed instructions on readme, you will need two terminals

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend if you are trying to run this on your PC, then I would go down the Docker route; this would make it a little easier to have things run with more consistency, among other things.

Comment: It's probably best they learn how to use npm before they tackle docker

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is not fulfilled. All directories with package.json needs installation.

If you go to client folder, it contains package.json, meaning it needs it's packages to be installed by running in client folder directory:

```
npm i
```

Note: Some project may depend on node version, try older versions instead while installing and running project.
For linux and macOS you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/n
For windows use https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

To run client side, run:

```
npm start
```

If starts successfully, React website should open automatically.

Later one, you need to set up MongoDB, by fulfilling connection to db in https://github.com/JustFS/mern-project/blob/master/config/db.js

Comment: The OP says in the comments that this didn't work